# Problem with showing button over google maps android

Tags: java, android, xml, maps

I'm using google maps in android. Trying to create a layout with google map and some other widgets on the screen like drawer icon. Here is my xml code.
The problem I'm facing is drawer icon is visible in xml design layout but when I run the application on device it is not visible.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment">


       <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" >
           <ImageView
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_orange"
               android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
               android:layout_marginLeft="20dp">
           </ImageView>
       </com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: UI design]

Comment: May I know what problem you are facing In question it is not clear.

Comment: UP, it's unclear. all data seems to retreived properly. If the problem is with "showing a button" over selected area, then it's hard to be targeted since there is no code which tries to show a button over google map

Comment: What is your problem???

Comment: Drawer image is visible in design view. But when I run the application it's not visible on map

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with maps but not with google maps, anyway have you tried putting the imageview in the relative layout instead of inside the MapView? RelativeLayouts are made for that purpose, so items init can overlap. not sure if a google maps mapview will accet an Imageview

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment">


   <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />


   <ImageView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_orange"
           android:layout_margin="20dp"
           android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
           android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
   </ImageView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

plus if you want it to look just like the image above I would recommend using a FloatingActionButton in place of the imageview

Comment: OP already use a ImageView, so is your code. Amd it look's that you just closed the MapView before ImageView tag, so the ImageView definitely won't be rendered where it's supposed to be. Also, if you're not sure of ImageView and in the same time you're recommending a button it would be good to include a code, just a declaration or at least a pseudocode with button.

Comment: ok I just changed the imageview constraints to align the image bottom right as seen in the image above. but the image will be shown on top of the map because this is a relativelayout. I am leaving the ImageView because there might be some other unknown reason for using an imageView in place of a button. I am assuming the image above isnt the actual app but just an example.

Comment: First I use imageview inside relative layout but image is even not visible in design layout.

Comment: have you tryed using a different drawable